# Modulo operation with index in CPLEX

Tags: cplex, modulo

I'm using CPLEX, I would like to use modulo operation for "d" index and I would like to set d+8 as a remainder of 28.  For instance, if d is 21, then (d+8)'s value should be 29 % 28=1 . "x" is a binary decision variable.

And I want something like that:

```
forall(e in employee, d in day) x[e][(d+8)%28]==x[e][d];
```

But it gives me an error. How can I do that in an appropriate way?
I'm very happy if you would help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
{string} employee={"me"};
range day=1..28;

dvar boolean x[employee][day];
minimize sum(e in employee,d in day) x[e][d];
subject to
{
  x["me"][1]==1;
 forall(e in employee, d in day) x[e][(d-1+8)%28+1]==x[e][d];
}

{int} x1PerEmployee[e in employee]={d | d in day : x[e][d]==1};

execute
{
  writeln(x1PerEmployee);
}
```

gives

```
[{1 5 9 13 17 21 25}]
```